# Cannot open source file "pthread.h"

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using visual studio and include it in my stdafx.h

Comment: pthreads don't exist on Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows isn't Unix. It has its own threading API, accessible through `<windows.h>`. Or, if you have C++11, you can write portable threading applications with the new library facilities.